# Collection regex filtering issue

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have such expression;

```
collection = collection.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "[a-zA-Z0-9+#-\\.\\s]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

before filtering, collection have such elements:

```
a+1, a#1, a-1, a.1, a 1, ab, a'1, a@1, a*1, a&1, a:1, a!1
```

after, I want only following elements to stay:

```
a+1, a#1, a-1, a.1, a 1, ab
```

but no element is thrown away.

I need to preserve only elements which consist of: letters, numbers, plus, hash, minus, dot, whitespaces.

How to correct this regex expression ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex checks if the element *contains a substring* matching the text. Since all of your elements contain `a` (which matches the regular expression), all elements are preserved.

If you want the substring to *match exactly*, enclose your regular expression in `^...$` (marking the beginning and the end of the text):

```
... Regex.IsMatch(x, "^[a-zA-Z0-9+#-\\.\\s]+$", ...
```

**EDIT**: In addition, you need to move the dash `-` to the end of the group:

```
... Regex.IsMatch(x, "^[a-zA-Z0-9+#\\.\\s-]+$", ...
```

Otherwise, `#-\\.` matches all characters from `#` to `.`.

Comment: Thanks but I still have problems, for some reason 3 unwanted elements: a'1, a*1 and a&1, are still there, which is some kind of nonsense.

Comment: @JarekWaliszko: You are right, there was another bug in your regexp. I've edited by answer.

Comment: Thank you, good tip, btw: regular expressions are for people who really like hardcore mind puzzles ;]

Comment: I always use the @ sign for regexp strings in C# so I don't have to escape every backslash. Then your code would look like  Regex.IsMatch(x, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9+#\.\s-]+$" ...
a bit more readable

Comment: @mortb: Thanks, I know but it wasn't possible in my case, because my pattern is declared as const string as a member of my class.